# Google Sheets: Append then Delete rows based on Tickbox condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to create a spreadsheet to organise products ordered at my workplace.

When an order is received a team member would add the details to the sheet; when it is collected they'd fill out date and ID then tick the order complete. [See Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h86bV.png)
What I want to happen next is that the row containing the complete details from that order is appended to a second page in the sheet and the original row is deleted.

I can't make sense of how to get this to run automatically when the box is checked; so far I have been compiling a script to run from a button press:

```
function runFiling() {
  function moveRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var osh = ss.getSheetByName('Current');
  var dsh = ss.getSheetByName('Collected');
  var srg = osh.getDataRange('H2:H');//You might want to specify a more unique range. This just gets all of the data on the sheet
  var svA = srg.getValues();
  var d=0;//deleted row counter
  for(var i=1;i<svA.length;i++) {
    if(svA[i][7] =='TRUE') {
      dsh.appendRow(svA[i]);//append entire row to Sheet2
      osh.deleteRow(i-d+1);//accounts for the difference between length of array and number of remaining row.
      d++;
    }
  }
}
}
```

However even this fails to Append or Delete anything although no errors are found/returned.

If anyone can suggest a way to fix the above or, preferably, how to make the script work when the box is ticked your help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way using an onEdit(e) function

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Current' && e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    const dsh = ss.getSheetByName('Collected');
    const vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()
    dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

This will accomplish the task line by line as the check boxes are checked off by the user.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
onEdit @ CodeOE.gs:2
Can I just specify a column to check?

Comment: This is not the type of function that you can call from the editor or a menu since it requires the event object from the trigger just edit the appropriate page.  I often add e.source.toast() flags to debug these functions.